# Dynamic Pages with html5 + XML + JS?

Tags: javascript, xml, json, html

Basically this is the first time when i ASK A QUESTION on stackoverflow. Anyway i will really appreciate if someone can point me to some direction about creating an simple product catalog app using html5+xml+js.

Well the structure is the following:

A: **Home page** >click> **Product Categ** >click> **List of Products** >click> **Product Page Description**

I'm not sure how shall i create the dynamic pages for the products to be able to extract all the products description from XML whenever click on any of product from the list page.

For example i have 10 products on the page, when i click on product **X**, an dynamic page with the product **X** 's (image, description, price) to be created, and so on.

I hope all of these things make sense for you and thanks a lot for your precious time.

Comment: Consider using a CMS, Joomla drupal worldpress...

Comment: HI, basically i dont want to create any ecommerce app. As i want to create something simple, without php & mysql, or asp.net, but i don't want to create many html files.

Comment: It will be a **LOT** simpler to use php and a database than it will be to use JavaScript and XML files....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading XML files using JavaScript, check answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199180/read-xml-file-using-javascript). For HTML5 and JavaScript in general I suggest you to check tutorials for some basics:

- JavaScript - http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp
- HTML5 - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp

You can also check [jQuery library tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp). And [here](http://jquery.com/) is jQuery's website.

I think that you should read some basics to learn how to look for more in the web and search for "how-to" connected with specified things you want to do and still don't know where to start.

**EDIT:**

If you want to check something that you'll need exactly at the beginning, you can check [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) of addEventListener JavaScript method that will allow you to set action that will be invoked when particular event of the element fires. You can also check links connected to jQuery I mentioned above - jQuery is JavaScript library that makes writing JS simplier. But with both JavaScript and jQuery you have to spend some time reading documentation to know what you can do and how to achieve it.

Comment: I've dont a lot of research and after lots of hours trying to figure it out i decided to ask for some help, idea, something....

Comment: @iNvidia So tell us what you already know and what is a problem. I provided you 2 solutions for loading XML using JS. Rest of your question is about general programming with JavaScript. If you have never done anything with JavaScript, check the tutorial to learn some basics. There are a lot of sources in the web. I updated my answer with more info.