# Dynamic HTML5 Player with XML and Buttons

Tags: javascript, xml, html, media-player

I am currently developing a website for a gaelic school. Currently they use Flash for a web application, which I'll link to below, however I'm in the process of attemptting to create/re-create it in HTML5 as it's currently not able to be accessed by everyone.

THe application consists of buttons, all of which are drawn by XML input, and another XML file contains the mp3 data that is played when each button is pressed. One XML file draws the boxes, whilst the other populates them.

A link to this application: "http://ceres.napier.ac.uk/staff/alistair/gaelicparenthelp/ff_sets.html"

As you can see when one button is clicked, more appear.

I've tried following guides for HTML5 media players however I don't fully understand how to read the XML files in to create these formats as shown. I've looked into tree formats as well, but can't find a good place to start either.

If anyone could send me in the right direction I'd be very greatful, my searches keep letting me down halfway as theya ren't exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [Read XML file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199180/read-xml-file-using-javascript) or jQuery's `load` and selectors to read your XML file.

For the HTML elements, the best option might be to take advantage of dynamic elements creation.
Here is a demo to Read XML data:

```js
var xml= '<ASSETS><Box ><id>1</id><url>bogsa01.xml</url><text>Bogsa1</text></Box><Box ><id>2</id><url>bogsa02.xml</url><text>Bogsa2</text></Box><Box ><id>3</id><url>bogsa03.xml</url><text>Bogsa3</text></Box><Box ><id>4</id><url>bogsa04.xml</url><text>Bogsa4</text></Box></ASSETS>';

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ); 
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
var $box = $xml.find("Box");

$box.each(function(){
   var id = $(this).find('id').text();
   var text = $(this).find('text').text();
   var url = $(this).find('url').text();
   // From here you can do whatever you want with the data 
   $("#BoxList" ).append('<li><b>ID: </b>' +id+ '  <b>TEXT: </b> '+text+ '  <b>URL: </b> ' +url+ '</li>'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="BoxList">XML:</div>
```

Comment: Okay I've came across that a few times and fairly understand it. The XML I'm working with also handles box id's and url's like so:

Comment: <ASSETS>
  <Box id="1" url="bogsa01.xml">Bogsa1</Box>
  <Box id="2" url="bogsa02.xml">Bogsa2</Box>
  <Box id="3" url="bogsa03.xml">Bogsa3</Box>
  <Box id="4" url="bogsa04.xml">Bogsa4</Box>
Didn't mean to reply there, but yes... would it still be the best method?