# Move desktop game to web

Tags: web, graphics

I developed simple game using C#, Windows Forms and graphics library SFML.

[Fire Tank Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TyVL.png)

The game goal is to develop algorithm that performs by tanks (moving, shooting, etc) to extinguish the fire on the map.

This game can draw some kind of simple graphics, works with XML (to draw map, that opens from .xml file), has simple GUI (menu, combobox, datagridview, buttons, labels), uses API (Entity Framework) to query some data from small DB in SQL Server.

Now I would like try to turn it into web. So I need help with what languages (python, php, javascript?) and libraries I should use to develop the same game in web. In total necessary features:

1. Draw graphics.
2. Draw GUI.
3. Work with DB (Also, I would like to move data into some cloud DB, e.g. Azure).
4. Work with XML.

Also, I implemented simple "sign in/up" logic. Is there any library that registers user and adds him to the DB? So, fifth featureis:

5. Sign in/up feature.

Last, game uses inconvenient way to develop algorithms (users need to choose items of algorithm from combobox). Is there some library that allows to do it with "drag & drop" way?

6. Drag & drop items to the table (datagridview).

Comment: Unity. Scripting is in C# so some of your code will be reusable, and the web player works really well.

Comment: I know about Unity, but I would like to practice programming in other languages. Some of these (python, php, javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside of Unity, as suggested, I can recommend you a Javascript library called [**p5**](https://p5js.org/reference/).

I worked with both, [sfml](/questions/tagged/sfml) and [p5](/questions/tagged/p5) and, saving the distances, they are pretty similar.

You can **draw 2D stuff** (circles, lines, rectangles, etc) with it.

It also contains **GUI components** to work with (buttons, sliders, etc).

If you want a web environment, you surely will have/need a server side, probably based on PHP to access database. Alternatively, you can use a [JS database library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/database-js), if your system is simple enough.

You can [read XML files with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199180/read-xml-file-using-javascript) but you would probably prefer to use **JSON files**.

Maybe this can cover your basic needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are two good options:

A: Convert it: https://bridge.net/

B: Unity, as 3Dave stated