# How to read/get information from live stream manifest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, live-streaming

Am running a drm widfine live stream and I like to get some information from the manifest. I found a website:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getManifest#Syntax

but if I run this code I get a: 'browser' is not defined  no-undef.

```
var manifest = browser.runtime.getManifest();
console.log(manifest.name);
```

Comment: where did you run that code?

Comment: I run it in chrome  @ducmai

Comment: Chrome extension / app?

Comment: Presumably you want to actually work with the live stream's manifest, right?  That has nothing to do with the method you're linking to.

Comment: Are you trying to run it in a context of an addon? Because if you try to run it in the regular browser, it will not work..

Comment: @MoshFeu and I have a normal chrome browser with some small extantions to help me. I have a application that runs encrypted live-streams (DRM). Now i want to now what the bandwidth is and more information.... This information is in the manifest that i get every 2-5 seconds in my network tab. I want to now how to collect the data from this manifest file in my network tab.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with that are. But is this what you're looking for? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getManifest

Comment: And this is an example of how to check the interent speed and so: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/network-information/

Comment: @MoshFeu I don't think this is wat am looking for it just a react application where am running it in. I can read the information in the manifest file by doing F12 but i need to get the information from in my app. 

I think i can do it by browser.runtime.getManifest() but i get browser undifend

Comment: So you can't :) because there is no such an API. The docs are saying specifically that this api is available for extensions / addons / apps only.

Comment: That sad am still searching for a way to do it in react.js. I think that there must be some smart person that can find a way or can make it. But tanks @MoshFeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the manifest file, you can use the manifest URL which you use to load the stream. This link will give you a file with the needed information for the stream, then you use JavaScript to read out the XML file each time a stream is loaded.

Within the file, you can find the bitrate data. Within your player you should be able to find the bitrate that its currently playing at.

[Read XML file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199180/read-xml-file-using-javascript)

Comment: Thank you fo the anwser am now going to try this