# Show XML file all content in Textarea using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I want to display an XML file's content in a `<textarea>` as the user selects the file from the HTML input file type. I have made some code for it but instead of showing XML value in `<textarea>`, it is showing the path of the XML file.

Please take a look at my code and tell me what should I do to show XML file content in `<textarea>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.file').bind("change", function() {
    $('.textarea').val($('.file').val())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' class='file'>
<textarea class='textarea'></textarea>
```

Comment: You cannot read an XML file by means of jQuery `val()` method. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199180/read-xml-file-using-javascript.

Comment: I want to use jQuery to do it, can you suggest me what else I should do instead of val()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a file you have to use a FileReader object, it takes the File object from the file input and you can read it as text and display it in your text area.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.file').bind("change",function() {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
    fr.onload = e => {
      $('.textarea').val(e.target.result);
    }        
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' class='file'>
<textarea class='textarea'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a file in javascript, you have to use a `FileReader`

you can try something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.file').bind("change",function() {
    // get file xml from input
    let fileXML = document.getElementById("file").files[0]
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(fileXML);
    fileReader.onloadend = function(){
         $('.textarea').val(fileReader.result)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="file" type='file' class='file'>
<div>
  <textarea class='textarea' rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
```

demo jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/t5f71mos/